# how can i include an array as react-router-dom parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, uri

I want to pass an array as a `react-router-dom` parameter like so:

```
website.com/[a,b,c]/
```

this works when I type this directly into the search bar and turn it into an array with the following code:

```
JSON.parse(arrayParam)
```

after which I can use it as an array.

problem is that when I send someone the above link, the link becomes:

```
website.com/%5ba,b,c%5d/
```

and it stops working.
I've tried the following:
passing the array as
`website.com/a,b,c`
and using

```
arrayParam.split(',')
```

does not become an array

I've tried decoding the URI `website.com/%5ba,b,c%5d` with:

```
  const decodedArrayParam = decodeURI(arrayParam);
  const myArray = JSON.parse(decodedArrayParam);
  console.log(myArray);
```

which console logs `undefined`
same happens when I also encode the ',': `https://example.com/my-page/%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D/`
or when U use `decodeURIComponent' instead

which gives me the same error. I've tried using `toString` to parse the URI param first, with no success.

Any solutions or workarounds that would achieve the same thing? Or any way to prevent the original link from changing?

In my app.js I have:

```
 <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path={`/:arrayParam`}
            element={<Main className= 
           {styles.main} />}
          />
        </Routes>
</Router>
```

in main.js I have for the regular method with `website.com/[1,2,3]/`:

```
import {useParams, useSearchParams} from 'react-router-dom';
const RouterParams = useParams()
const myArray = JSON.parse(RouterParams.arrayParam);
```

This is working, can use the array

for the splitting method with `website.com/1,2,3/`

```
import {useParams, useSearchParams} from 'react-router-dom';
const RouterParams = useParams()
const myArray = (RouterParams.arrayParam).split(',');
console.log(myArray)
```

This is not working, gives undefined.

or, for the URL decoding with `website.com/%5Ba%2Cb%2Cc%5D/` or `website.com/%5Ba,b,c%5D/`

```
import {useParams, useSearchParams} from 'react-router-dom';
const RouterParams = useParams()
const myArrayParam = (RouterParams.arrayParam)
const decodedArrayParam = decodeURIComponent(myArrayParam);
const myArray = JSON.parse(decodedArrayParam);
console.log(myArray)
```

This also gives undefined

I also have the following in main.js, to prevent users from going back to a previous page. Somehow, this prevents me from using regular URL parameters because they are immediately removed

```
    useEffect(() => {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
        window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
        };
    }, []);

    // Alert a warning if people try to go back to previous page
    const onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!finishStatus) {
            if (window.confirm(
                "You cannot go back to a previous page, \
                Please close the window if you wish to exit")
            ) {
                setfinishStatus(true)
                // your logic
            } else {
                window.history.pushState(null, null, 
                window.location.pathname);
                setfinishStatus(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this array ***need*** to be part of the URL path? I don't think arrays lend themselves well to this part of a URL. It would likely be better to move this value to the queryString parameters. It will be easier to process and it won't be involved in route path matching.

Comment: @DrewReese Ideally, yes. querystrings are not working for me because other logic in my react app automatically removes them (something with ` window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);'` for sending users a warning on going back to a previous page.

Comment: Well that seems like a problem you should rectify. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] that includes this other code that strips out the queryString?

Comment: @DrewReese added both to the post, thanks

Comment: It is generally considered poor UI/UX to "trap" users on a page. Can you clarify the exact use case here? Why can't you just show the confirmation window alerting the user that they've some unfinished business on the page and that if they confirm ("OK") that it will be lost? Where does this `main.js` code get rendered in the app in relation to the router/routes and the `Main` component? Can you walk us through the UX flow and explain what could/should happen, or what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
const params = searchParams.getAll('aisle'); 
console.log(params) //Prints ["1","4"].
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a workaround is to try with `atob` and `btoa` method using `window`.

For example,

Pass this array as parameters in URL,

```
arrayParam = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(window.btoa(['a', 'b', 'c'])); // YSxiLGM=
```

To get the exact array on the other side,

```
window.atob("YSxiLGM").split(",");  // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) for this

Comment: Thanks! In theory, that should work indeed. Somehow query strings aren't working in my whole react app that's why I'm trying to use react-router-dom instead.